# Storing blacklisted JWT

Tags: security, jwt

I need to store a list of blacklisted tokens, so far the examples that i have seen are about storing them in redis and if they are not blacklisted then the app query another database like mongo  to get the user.
 I want to store them in a sub-document in user with a jti claim, is it a good idea, in practice how many blacklisted token a user can have.

Answer (score 1):

If using the `jti` claim also to mitigate replay attacks, then essentially you want to "blacklist" *all of them* after processing once. Hence your list can grow large, even per individual user.

In general I do not see a benefit of storing blacklisted tokens on a per-user basis. On the contrary, in terms of scaling that would likely limit you at some point in case you later want to isolate the blacklisting feature into an independent service/architecture, which is probably why you see others do it that way.